# Realloc() Unable to understand even after lots of reading

Tags: c, memory, embedded

I am writing a simple task scheduler and using dynamic memory allocation on my Texas Instruments cc430F5137 which has 4kB RAM. I agree that it is not a good practice but for the time being lets assume it is my application requirement to use dynamic memory allocation.

In my OS.c file

I have two structures,

```
typedef struct
{
    task_t task;
    uint8_t next;
    uint8_t prev;
    uint8_t priority;

} info_t;


typedef struct
{
    task_t task;
    uint8_t index;
} index_t;
```

size of `info_t` is 8 bytes and size of `index_t` is 6 bytes.

Also I do

```
index_t* m_index;
info_t* m_info;
```

Then I have initialize function in which I do

```
m_info = NULL;
m_index = NULL;
```

Now I have a function `registerTask(& task)` which takes address of the function to schedule. In this function I do

```
m_info = (info_t*)realloc(m_info,(num_registered_tasks + 1) * sizeof(info_t));
```

and then set the values of .priority, next,task and prev.

Then I do

```
m_index = (index_t*)realloc(m_index,(num_registered_tasks + 1) * sizeof(index_t));
```

and set the values of task and index.
 and do `num_registered_tasks++;`

My Question is that how is `realloc()` behaving in this regard.

Suppose my memory space,
First Task is registered, so It will have first 8 bytes for `m_info[0]` and next 6 bytes for `m_index[0]`.
Now when my second task calls this function, what will happen? What I am guessing is that for m_info it will first look for 16 bytes of continuous data and will only find it after the first 14 bytes, it will change the address of `m_info[0]` and copy the contents and then add `m_info[1]`. And when `m_index` is called, it will only find 12 bytes after this (14 + 16) bytes and place `m_index[0]` and `m_index[1]` here.

Please have a look at the picture
[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH58G.jpg

**How can I utilize the previous space also?**

I need `index_t` struct for implementing some sort of search algorithm so it is necessary also

Comment: I don't think it's `realloc()`'s fault. From a first look you have a few issues `m_info = (info_t*)realloc(m_info,(num_registered_tasks + 1) * sizeof(info_t));`, 1. Don't use the cast, 2. Don't overwrite the `m_info` poitner without checking that `realloc()` did not return `NULL`.

Comment: Well I guess not, can so please point to some work around?

Comment: In C, `m_info = realloc(m_info,(num_registered_tasks + 1) * sizeof(*m_info));`

Comment: @SinanÜnür or `void *pleaseKeepTheOldData = realloc(m_info,(num_registered_tasks + 1) * sizeof(*m_info)); if (pleaseKeepTheOldData != NULL) m_info = pleaseKeepTheOldData;`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quiet get, Why did you change the argument of sizeof()?

Comment: @iharob Of course, I was just pointing out the unnecessary cast, and `sizeof` referring to something other than what's in that line. I still can't understand the question, but that's a different matter. ;-)

Comment: @Hassan even if you change the type of `m_info`, `m_info = malloc(sizeof(*m_info))` will remain correct.

Comment: Thanks I get this but this is the add on. My question still remains.

Comment: A wild guess: You haven't provided the definition of `struct task_t`, so make sure that each field in it is properly aligned (according to its size). In addition to that, if any of these fields is **larger than** 16 bits, then add `uint8_t reserved[2]` at the end of `struct index_t`.

Comment: Are you asking how do malloc and friends allocate space and how are they optimized for resizing?

Comment: You might well get wasted space, but that's the price you pay for flexible memory allocation. I worked with one MCU whose library implementation contains pools of different size blocks available, say 8, 16, 32 etc. In your case the 6-byte and the 8-byte `struct` will be allocated memory from the 8-byte pool. When you `realloc` the memory a new block will be allocated from the 16-byte pool, the data copied, and the previous 8-byte block returned to its pool. If there isn't a 16-byte block available, a 32-byte bock is split into two 16-byte blocks and they are added to that pool.

Comment: @rpattiso Yes. Because what I guess it is using first fit algorithm. What I am thinking is that may be use some other algorithm and optimize my space utilization.

Comment: @WeatherVane. Thanks I am using cc430F5137. At the moment I am not sure if it has this memory pools. I will look into this.

Comment: As your questions is now, it is unclear what you're asking, the post doesn't include an MCVE and it doesn't include the details needed to answer how the implementation defined parts of realloc will work on your system. Could you revise?

Comment: @Hassan : The availability of a fixed-block memory allocator is nothing to do with the hardware (cc430F5137), it would be provided by the operating system, or a library or implemented by yourself.  It is typically done by creating a FIFO queue of pointers to pre-allocated memory blocks, allocation takes a pointer from the queue and releasing returns a pointer to the queue.

Comment: @Clifford. Thanks I get the basic idea. It would be great if you can point me to some resource which explains this in more detail and its implementation. Or if you can answer, shall I start a new question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots and lots of comments and answers of not using dynamic memory, I still found a way which at the time being solved my problem.

I changed this in my code

```
typedef struct
{
    task_t task;
    uint8_t next;
    uint8_t prev;
    uint8_t priority;

} info_t;


typedef struct
{
    task_t task;
    uint8_t index;
} index_t;

typedef struct
{
    info_t m_info;
    info_t m_index;
} combined_t;

combined_t* m_combined;
```

By this, nw my realloc() allocates contiguous memory to m_combined and my fragmentation issue is resolved. (Well I guess because after analyzing the memory step by step).

Answer (score 2):

> If this is true then all my previous space is being wasted?

No; if `realloc()` *moves* rather then extends an allocation, the previous allocation is released back to the heap and can be used by subsequent allocations.

What you will undoubtedly do is cause fragmentation of blocks, increase the change of allocation failure and experience widely varying allocation times.

If you must use `realloc()` you should probably use an algorithm that reduces the frequency of block moves by allocating multiple blocks at a time.  For example, when the initial allocation is required, rather then allocate one block allocate 16; subsequent tasks can use one of the 16 pre-allocated blocks (deterministically).  When these are exhausted, allocate a further 16 rather than just one.  Alternatively you might use a geometric progression, say starting with 4 blocks, then 8, 16, 32 perhaps to some maximum, so that thereafter the increment is fixed at 32.  This will reduce fragmentation and the changes of having to allocate and move data.

Comment: Thanks. It is some good advice. However have you heard about Buddy Alocator System algorithm? I just came across it. It has some fixed size memory blocks and assigns if according to need is one is requested. What do you suggest if it will work in my case because I always have fixed size of 8 bytes and 6 bytes